# How can I use state inside recompose's `withPropsOnChange` HOC?

Tags: reactjs, recompose

I want to use [`withPropsOnChange`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#withpropsonchange) to create a new [debounced](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce) function based on the props that were passed in. If the props are changed, it should create a new function. `withPropsOnChange` seems perfect for this, *except* that I need access to `this.state` inside of the `createProps` callback, which recompose doesn't provide.

What are the alternatives? i.e. how can I create a property (React or vanilla) that's contingent/depends-on on some other properties and is automatically updated when those props are updated?

---

Here's the gist of what I've got now:

```js
class MyClass extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isOpen: false,
            isLoading: 0,
            isWaiting: false,
            searchQuery: '',
            options: [],
            value: undefined, 
            highlightedValue: undefined,
            scrollPos: 0,
        };
        if(props.options) {
            this.loadOptions = Lo.debounce(searchQuery => {
                this.setState(state => ({
                    isLoading: state.isLoading + 1,
                }));
                props.options(searchQuery).then(result => {
                    this.setState(state => ({
                        isLoading: state.isLoading - 1,
                        options: result.options,
                    }));
                });
            }, props.delay);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm defining a property called `this.loadOptions` which is just a debounced copy of `props.options` with some state handling.

This works adequately for now, but if the upstream modifies `props.options` or `props.delay`, then `this.loadOptions` *won't* be updated because I'm only doing this in the constructor.

Now I *could* do all this again in `componentWillUpdate`, but really I only want to do it if either `props.options` or `props.delay` are updated, because those are its only two dependencies.

I'm just looking for a cleaner design pattern to deal with this sort of thing. It's basically just "computed properties" now that I think about it (but I can't "recompute" it as needed -- I need the same instance back each time unless those properties are modified).

Comment: 100k reputation and such a low quality title?

Comment: @slick ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ It had all the important keywords. I've updated the title.

Comment: No worries and no offence Mark, all good! :)

Comment: Could you perhaps write some psudo-code to further explain how the flow/logic of the program should be? Or maybe more details about the use-case. I'm having trouble seeing what the problem is.. But that may very well just be my slow brain.

Comment: @jonahe I've updated the question with a more concrete example.

Answer (score 1):

So, as I understand it, you have some state that is currently internal to the component. And you would like to use that state inside of the `createProps` callback.

Would it be possible to use recompose to extract that internal state (and its logic), with [`withState`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#withstate)?

Then, if you "start" the composing of recompose functions with the `withState`, state should be available "further down" as props. (Or at least that's my understanding.)

```js
const enhance = compose(
  // handle previously internal state
  withState('importantState', 'changeImportantState', 0),
  withHandlers({
    logicForChangingTheImportantState:
        props => () => props.changeImportantState(old =>  ({...old, moreImportant: 'xyz'}))
  }),
    // do your logic here
  withPropsOnChange(
    [], // ?? shouldMapOrKeys
    (props) => {
        return {
        thisPreviouslyDependedOnInternalState: props.importantState
      }
    }    
  ) 
);
```

Comment: I might be able to move all the state into props via `withState`, but then I have to move all my handlers over too (like you've shown), which is a bit more refactoring than I wanted to do.

Comment: Ok yeah, that's understandable. It's considerably easier to "externalize" state like that when you write the code for the first time. I once tried getting into the habit of only writing simple/dumb functional components and handling all the state with `withState` (and redux). But even then, when I didn't need to refactor anything, it was kind of hard and un-intuitive to code like that. So my experiment didn't last for long. /end of pointless storytime.

Comment: I did basically the same thing. Tried putting all my state in my components. Then I discovered recompose, tried making everything 'dumb' for awhile, and then I decided this component was too complicated to make dumb, so I started writing it the old fashioned way, and then discovered one or two things would be much easier with recompose, so I brought a couple of those HOCs back in... and now I've got this mess.